# How to fix a Run-time error '13': Type mismatch that is resonating from VBA code?

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I am getting this error based off this part of the code -

```
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Path + "/Roll Call Report_" + strCenter + " " + Format(Str(Sheets("Summary & Instructions").Range("K1").Value), "mmddyy") + ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
```

I'm kind of at a loss as to why this is failing.  Full code below -

```
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
strCenter = (Sheets("Summary & Instructions").Range("L1").Value)
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Path + "/Roll Call Report_" + strCenter + " " + Format(Str(Sheets("Summary & Instructions").Range("K1").Value), "mmddyy") + ".xlsx", FileFormat:=51
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

What am I missing?

Comment: `Sheets("Summary & Instructions").Range("L1").Value` or `Sheets("Summary & Instructions").Range("K1").Value` contain an error, or a number. Type your variables and use the [`&` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/ampersand-operator) for string concatenation.

Comment: I am somewhat unsure, its flagging that entire line.

Comment: Of course it is flagging that entire line because that entire line is a single expression that causes the error. Which is due to either an error value or a number in the cell. An error value would cause type mismatch anyway, the number would cause type mismatch only when it's `+`'ed with a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `&` for string concatenation and do not convert the date value. Adding the leading space into the format mask shortens things up.

You can let the FileFormat argument assign the correct file extension.

```
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/Roll Call Report_" & strCenter & Format(Sheets("Summary & Instructions").Range("K1").Value, " mmddyy"), FileFormat:=51
```